# Unable to send embedded image in email using FluentEmail

Tags: email, html-email, asp.net-core-2.0, fluent-interface

I'm using [FluentEmail](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail) in ASP.NET core 2.0 class library which will be sending the Email notification.

Below is the sample code I have tried till now:

```
using FluentEmail.Core;
using FluentEmail.Razor;
using FluentEmail.Smtp;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;

namespace FluentEmail
{
    public class EmailNotification : IEmailNotification
    {
        public bool SendEmailNotification()
        {
            try
            {
                //Setup Default sender befault sending the email.
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
                {
                   Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                   Port = 587,
                   EnableSsl = true,
                   Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "Password")
                };
                Email.DefaultSender = new SmtpSender(smtpClient);

                Email.DefaultRenderer = new RazorRenderer();

                string imagePath = @"C:\Users\pratik.soni\Downloads\FluentLogo.png";

                Stream stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var attachment = new Core.Models.Attachment()
                {
                    Data = stream,
                    ContentType = "image/png",
                    Filename = "FluentLogo.png",
                    IsInline = true
                };

                var email = Email
                  .From("pratik.soni@1rivet.com")
                  .To("pratik.soni10@gmail.com")
                  .Subject("Test")
                  .Body("<html>Inline image here: <img src=\"cid:FluentLogo.png\">" +
                    "<p>You should see an image without an attachment, or without a download prompt, dependig on the email client.</p></html>", true);

                email.Attach(attachment);
                email.Send();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My HTML file is as follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>FluentEmail - Test with template and attachment</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #e5e5e5;" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" leftmargin="0">
<!--100% body table-->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#d8e7ea" style="background-color: #e5e5e5;">
            <!--intro-->
            <table width="620" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" width="11" height="100"></td>
                    <td valign="middle" height="100">
                        <!--break-->
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--/break-->
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="59%" height="100">
                                    <table width="280" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#333333">
                                                <h1 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 42px; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #fff;">Typographic</h1>
                                                <p style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;  color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                                    <currentdayname>
                                                    <currentday>
                                                    <currentmonthname>
                                                    <currentyear>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="41%" height="100" valign="top">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="bottom" height="70">
                                                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #333; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; padding: 0;"> Email not looking beautiful?<br>
                                                    <webversion style="text-decoration: none; color: #cc0000">View it in your browser</webversion>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--break-->
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--/break-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--/intro-->
            <!--content section-->
            <table width="620" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td height="82" width="11" valign="middle"></td>
                    <td height="82" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="middle">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="middle" height="37" bgcolor="#fef041">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="25" height="37"></td>
                                            <td width="15" height="37"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <h2 style="color: #333333 !important; font-size: 21px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;"> @Model.Title</h2>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">
                        <table width="560" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <p style="font-size: 14px; color: #333333; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> Dear @Model.Name, You are totally @Model.Compliment. </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <table bgcolor="#000000" width="540" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
           <td>
            <img src=\"cid:@Model.ImgSrc\">
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                                            <td width="540" height="158"><img style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" border="0" src="C:\Users\pratik.soni\Downloads\2016-fluent-logo-design-digital-marketing-20nine-4.png" width="540" height="158" alt="img1"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--/100% body table-->
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried with only passing image path to the imgsrc in html but that is also not working.

Please let me know what I'm missing in here.

Also, is there any such package like **FluentEmail** which can provide such all facility with **ASP.NET Core 2.0**?

Comment: REF: https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail/issues/101

Comment: Even if are able to embed images to an email there are very patchy support for rendering. Campaign monitor has an article [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/) which shows each client and if it renders embedded images properly.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but if the client wants something we have to provide that right? :) But yes, thnx for sharing the information @Syfer.

Comment: You can provide but before you provide you have to tell them if they are adamant and only want embedded images then they can say goodbye to users who are using non supported email clients as they will not see the image(s). As an email dev its our job to educate them and tell them what works and what doesn't (you know that i know).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a LinkedResource; have a look at this

```
using (LinkedResource image = new LinkedResource(@"c:\assets\image.jpg", "image/jpeg") { ContentId = "myimage" })
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.alfki.com";

    String body = @"
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>    
        <img src=""cid:myimage"" />      
        </body>
    </html>
    ";  

    AlternateView view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
    view.LinkedResources.Add(image);

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(view);
    mail.From = new MailAddress("John.Doe@alfki.com");
    mail.To.Add("Jane.Doe@alfki.com");
    mail.Subject = "An email with an inline image";

    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

**Edit:**

It works in .NET Core/Standard.

I can not speak for FluentMail; maybe you can do without?

Comment: Yes, I know that it can be done without FluentEmail. But the concern here is it has to be done with FluentEmail, otherwise, I have already sample code ready using other approaches.

Comment: OK, but I read "is there any such package like ..." and therefor decided to let you know it can be done without. Any good reasons to stick with FluentMail?

Comment: Client's requirement! Can't help it. They want it to be "fluent". 

Anyway, I have found some other fluent option i.e. **EmaFluent**. The only issue I'm facing with it is not all supporting all its functionality with Asp.Net Core 2.0. Though it is providing enough options for me what I want. The concern is it is displaying a small warning message on package.

Comment: If a commerical library is an option; have a look at [Limilabs Mail.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mail.dll) with support for .NET Core 2.0+ and .NET Standard 2.0+. There is a fluent example to embed an image [here](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/sending-email-with-embedded-image).

Comment: Commercials are not options. I have tried that too. :) Even in free-packages, I have suggested MailKit / MimeKit which is allowing all the facilities in free (as per my knowledge).

Comment: Even in this FluentEmail if we had  **MailGun** option is available then we could have send image in inline body. But this option is rejected too.

Comment: Client is king! You noticed that EmaFluent is quite outdated ; I see 2014 on NuGet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172054/discussion-between-pratik-soni-and-pfx).